# How to count consciousness?

Tags: sentence-construction, plural-forms, uncountable-nouns, word-form

I'm afraid I'm talking about my favourite topic, consciousness, wrong. Can you please check which of these cases of my trying to use the word on Reddit are correct?

> 1. "Quantum wave form collapses after every interaction. So you don't need an observer and you don't need ***a*** consciousness to explain quantum physics."
> 2. "But yeah, all possibilities might be true if parallel universes exist. The question is whether we can suppose that other *consciousness**es*** in other universes are as conscious as we are - because we can't be sure those universes actually "exist" unless we ourselves experience them."
> 3. "If you look into the polls, most philosophers think there's actually no "threshold" - in the sense that there can be a lot and **a little of** *consciousness*."
> 4. "I think utilitarianism can be broaden to maximizing happiness for the maximum number of ***consciousnesses***."

Comment: I don't know why someone voted to close as proofreading, but that's nuts. The question is about plurals and article usage for a single specific word, not generalized hunting for miscellaneous unidentified errors.

Comment: The question assumes that consciousness can exist in the plural :)

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo Aha! So I should rather say "utilitarianism can be broaden to maximizing happiness for the maximum number of bearers of consciousnesses."?

Comment: *Cogito ergo sum* gets you to consciousness. Not sure how to make the leap to the Other(s). But setting aside philosophical issues, **conscious beings** is probably more idiomatic than **consciousnesses**. Though phenomenologists are happy to use the plural --nesses

Comment: In my opinion, *consciousnesses* is tortured but perfectly understandable.  It displays gratuitivity and loquaciosity -- but many native speakers are equally guilty of making up words to fit.  :)

Answer (score 1):

Hmmm . . . it would seem that ***conciousness*** as a countable noun is used in the fields of philosophy and psychology according to the Oxford English Dictionary (see reference below). So, **a consciousness** and **consciousnesses** are both technically fine in those subjects. However, the plural form feels a little awkward in ordinary language. Perhaps "conscious entities* would be better.

The only problem I really spotted here is **a little of consciousness**.  Remove the **of**.

> Conciousness, n
>
> 2. *Philosophy and Psychology*.
>
> b. As a count noun. A state or form of consciousness. See also dream consciousness n. at dream n.2 and adj.
> Compounds 1a(b), false consciousness n. at false adj., adv., and n.
> Additions.
>
> *1915   R. W. Frazer Indian Thought ix. 181   This sect was known as Yogācāras; the only thing they would admit the reality of was a series of thoughts or consciousnesses.*

Source: ["consciousness, n." OED Online. Oxford University Press, June 2022. Web. 4 September 2022.](https://www.oed.com/view/Entry/39477?redirectedFrom=consciousness#eid)

**Note:** I've only included one attestation above, but there are many.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to me to be a matter of style. "Consciousness" first and foremost denotes a state or attribute of something. I'd prefer to say "a conscious being" or "conscious beings" because that seems to me to capture more clearly what you are trying to say in most of your examples. An exception is example 3 because there you clearly are talking about the attribute itself rather than things with that attribute.

Answer (score 0):

The only issue is with #3 where you are introducing a countable noun but not using one.   Make it consciousnesses and you all set.

Now, consciousnesses is an unusual construct and may sound at bit clunky at first usage, but it is accurate.